# Calculate cheapest shopping basket

Tags: algorithm, shopping-cart

Given a products table:

```
Products
ID | Name | PriceCents
```

And `bundles` which are collections of products which when bought together give a discount:

```
Bundles
ID | Name

BundleItem
BundleID | ItemID | QuantityRequired | DiscountPercent
```

Given a collection of item ID's and quantities in your `basket`, how do you calculate which bundles offer the best price for the customer?

I am thinking the only way to do this is brute force all combinations, but it doesn't seem very elegant.

As bundles can be user generated, there can be lots of them, and there could exist two bundles with the same items but with different discounts.

Comment: Could you explain "two bundles with the same items but with different discounts"? Why wouldn't you just keep the best discount?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "the best". The cheapest solution clearly is to by nothing at all.

Comment: @Sparkup sellers can create their own bundles, they might create a bundle that says "50 units for 20% discount" or "10 units for 30% discount".  In this case it should ignore the 50 units bundle as multiples of the 10 units bundle is better for the customer.

Comment: As the number of bundles are provided then we have to check all bundles and have to find maximum discount. But there are some other details that are not clear to me please provide those details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it using [dynamical programming](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?d1=tutorials&d2=dynProg&module=Static).

The main idea is that you have a binary representation of your bucket - varialbe `binBucket`. So, if the i-th bit is set to 1, it means that your bucket contains i-th product, and vice versa.

Then you have some array `A`, where `A[binBucket]` is the best price for the set which includes all products described by `binBucket` binary representation of current bucket.

At the beginning, you have `A[0]=0` as the price of an empty bucket is `0`.

Then, you iterate over all possible binary representation of a bucket(2<sup>N</sup> states/different buckets), and try to add all possible bundles. When you try to add bundle, your binary representation will be changing (as the price).

So, you will make updates

`A[binBucketCurrent + binBundle] = min(A[binBucketCurrent + binBundle], A[binBucketCurrent] + bundle.price)`

`binBundle` here is the binary representation of bundle, same as for bucket.

So, at the end you will have your best price in the array at the position **2<sup>N</sup>-1**

Overall efficiency is **O(2<sup>N</sup> M)**, where `M` is the number of bundles available, and `N` is the number of products.

**UPDATE:** Of course, there might be a lot of products, and you cannot fit them into variable as the binary mask. So, you may use `set`, but that will affect the efficiency a little, however, this is more intuitive approach.